# DirectX:- How to copy a pointer image data to the existing D2D1Bitmap?

Tags: xaml, uwp, directx, direct2d

I've 4 image byte array with the same resolution 640*480. I'm trying to copy the byte array data from memory if the D2D1Bitmap is already available. After copying, d2dContext.DrawBitmap(bitmap) method fails, Here is the code,

Any pointers on what I'm missing?

```
        if (bitmap == nullptr)
        {
            hr = m_d2dContext->CreateBitmap(D2D1::SizeU(width, height),
                buffer->Data,
                width * 4,
                //(width * height) / 2 * 3,
                D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)),
                //D2D1::BitmapProperties(D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_NV12,D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE)),
                &bitmap);
            if (FAILED(hr))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            D2D1_SIZE_F rtSize = m_d2dTargetBitmap->GetSize();
            D2D1_RECT_U rect = D2D1::RectU(
                0,
                0,
                rtSize.width,
                rtSize.height
            );
            hr = bitmap->CopyFromMemory(&rect , buffer->Data, width * 4);                
        }

        m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();               
        m_d2dContext->DrawBitmap(bitmap);
        //bitmap->Release();
        hr = m_d2dContext->EndDraw();
```

Comment: Do you check all HRESULT? are they all S_OK? Make sure you don't release the bitmap, or provide a small reproducing sample. Devil hides in details

Comment: Yes CopyFromMemory returns S_OK but call to DrawBitmap fails and yes I'm not releasing the bitmap as I've to reuse for subsequent calls. Here is the link to reproducible sample -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wTQ5ent4aMpLyKCNOv_9ll_2sAw3POh6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: How do you run into the issue with the code?

Comment: In the sample, we are subscribing to a argVideoFrame web cam frame in scenario1.xaml.cs which makes a call to Direct3DPanel.startRenderLoop (DirectXProject) which is where I’m facing this issue while reusing the already created ID2D1Bitmap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [ID2D1Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nn-d2d1-id2d1bitmap) is a context-bound resource, since it's created from a `ID2D1RenderTarget` interface using [ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/nf-d2d1-id2d1rendertarget-createbitmap(d2d1_size_u_constvoid_uint32_constd2d1_bitmap_properties_id2d1bitmap))

It means you cannot create a static `ID2D1Bitmap` and use it on multiple context like you do. When you do this, on `EndDraw`, you get messages like this one when debugging (since the DirectX Debug Layer is enabled thanks to the `options.debugLevel = D2D1_DEBUG_LEVEL_INFORMATION` we can see in the sample code), in the Visual Studio output window:

```
D2D DEBUG ERROR - The resource [00000194E6EDD838] was allocated by factory [00000194B3973918] and used with factory [0000000000000000].
```

In your context, one solution is to make the bitmap reference member of the `D3DPanel` class and use it the same way as you do:

```
public ref class D3DPanel sealed : public DirectXPanels::DirectXPanelBase
{
    ...
    ID2D1Bitmap* m_bitmap;
    ...
};

....

if (m_bitmap == nullptr)
{
    m_d2dContext->CreateBitmap(...,  &m_bitmap);
}
else
{
    m_bitmap->CopyFromMemory(&rect , buffer->Data, width * 4);                
}

m_d2dContext->BeginDraw();               
m_d2dContext->DrawBitmap(m_bitmap);
m_d2dContext->EndDraw();
```

PS: you shall Release the bitmap when you release the context, for example in class destructor.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Yeah it works now. A quick question on this, when I create a bitmap and release it after drawing, I'm seeing the memory consumed to be less (Say around 170 MB). But when I re-use the bitmap with the help of CopyFromMemory, I see the memory consumption slightly higher (around 250 MB). I was actually expecting this to behave the other way around. Any thoughts on why re-use of bitmap consumption could be higher?

Comment: D2D1 Bitmaps are GPU resources. Working with CPU & GPU mixes memory consumption & performance between CPU & GPU.